# Merge only select paths with JQ

Tags: json, jq

Here, I have two json data.

```json
{
  "full_name": "clbr/n64bootloader",
  "description": null,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/clbr/n64bootloader",
  "created_at": "2020-12-25T16:19:12Z",
  "language": "C",
  "stargazers_count": 199,
  "watchers_count": 199,
  "forks_count": 10, 
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/clbr/n64bootloader"
}
```

```json
{
  "full_name": "clbr/n64bootloader",
  "description": null,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/clbr/n64bootloader",
  "created_at": "2020-12-25T16:19:12Z",
  "language": "C",
  "stargazers_count": 220,
  "watchers_count": 220,
  "forks_count": 10, 
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/clbr/n64bootloader"
}
```

Here I want to merge some specified key(s) into an array. In this example, I like to merge `stargazers_count`, so the expected json to be resulted is like follows.

```json
{
  "full_name": "clbr/n64bootloader",
  "description": null,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/clbr/n64bootloader",
  "created_at": "2020-12-25T16:19:12Z",
  "language": "C",
  "stargazers_count": [199, 220],
  "watchers_count": 220,
  "forks_count": 10, 
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/clbr/n64bootloader"
}
```

How can I do this using jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function to merge inputs by path(s) as follows.

```
def f(p):
  reduce inputs as $in (p |= [.];
    reduce path(p) as $p (.;
      setpath($p; getpath($p) + [$in | getpath($p)])
    )
  );
```

Then you can simply do:

```
f(.stargazers_count)
```

```
f(.stargazers_count, .watchers_count)
```

Note that this updates only selected fields; the rest will remain unchanged.

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qIW7O4QeUV)</sup>
<sup>[Online demo (multiple paths)](https://jqplay.org/s/z4yW4Qy5O9)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to preserve the fields in f2.json (the second file) except for the specified field.  If that's the case, you could achieve the desired outcome by:

```
jq --argfile f1 f1.json '
  .stargazers_count |= [., $f1["stargazers_count"]]
' f2.json
```

Since --argfile is officially deprecated, you might like to investigate alternative mechanisms for providing f1.json, e.g. using --slurpfile or invoking jq along the lines of: `jq ... f2.json f1.json`

### Abstraction

If you want to write a script that expects an argument specifying the field to be aggregated, you could use the following as a guide:

```
jq --argfile f1 f1.json --arg field stargazers_count '
  .[$field] |= [., $f1[$field]]
' f2.json
```

Comment: Re "*Since --argfile is officially deprecated, you might like to investigate alternative mechanisms*", As the man says, you can use `--slurpfile` to achieve the same thing. `jq --slurpfile f1 f1.json '
  .stargazers_count |= [., $f1[0].stargazers_count]
' f2.json`